# column validation in 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath, validation

Hopefully I can explain this well enough,

I am working in 2013 and I have created a form with 21 fields. There are eight fields that are required from the start, one of those required fields has six options below it each one of those options requires that another field be filled out. Each one of those six options has a unique number and organization of additional fields that need to be populated.

I attempted to write a formula for column validation and I ran out of space for text. I also attempted to shorten the formula just to test it and it was unsuccessful.

Any help on how I could make this work out of the box (or in info path) would be great!

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that you can edit an edit form or new form of a list or library)

You will need to customize the form by using SharePoint Designer. Additionaly you'll need to add some Javascript that will contain the logic of the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be done with InfoPath. Add a unique validation rule for each field and as condition select your dropdown/options field "is equal to" whatever option you like: Add Rule -> New -> Validation.

So instead of validating anything in SharePoint, you just validate in InfoPath.